# c++ lib curl compilation confusion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to use libcurl in one of c++ application where I need to download a file from a server using this. I am using libcurl for this. But I am facing deficulties while compiling and linking it.I compiled libcurl and got only libcurl.lib and no dll file.

This is error.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 34343, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  34343.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53) : System::IServiceProvider IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(96): error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type 'IServiceProvider'
1>          compiler replacing '*' with '^' to continue parsing
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103): error C2371: 'IServiceProvider' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(53) : see declaration of 'IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(120): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(241): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(251): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6459): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.h(6461): error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\servprov.h(103) : IServiceProvider'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll : System::IServiceProvider'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a visual studio project in `libcurl\src\`. Are you using it? It works great for me.